# convert TSRANGE(Postgres) data type to string

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql

I have a Postgres Database column with the TSRANGE to store the datetime ranges. After performing the **sql alchemy** query i get the rows of the results which are further converted into the dictionary style python objects as seen in the code below:

```
def row2dict(row):
    d = {}
    for column in row.__table__.columns:
        d[column.name] = str(getattr(row, column.name)) # TSRANGE column returns this DateTimeRange(datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 11, 2, 16), datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 11, 9, 1, 30), '[)')

    return d
```

I want this function to return something like this **["2018-01-11 02:16:00","2018-01-11 09:01:30"].** for the particular column name which has the TSRANGE Datatype. For example, for the holidays_time column it can be something like this:  `"holidays_time": ["2018-01-11 02:16:00","2018-01-11 09:01:30"]`. However, at this moment current output is below:

**Current Output for the TSRANGE COLUMN:**

```
"holidays_time": DateTimeRange(datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 11, 2, 16), datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 11, 9, 1, 30), '[)')
```

**What i have tried so far:**
Convert this TSRANGE to DateTimeRange(python library) by using the code below:

```
d[column.name] = DateTimeRange(getattr(row, column.name))
```

Also if i do like this

```
d[column.name] = list(getattr(row, column.name))
```

to get the date ranges in a list so i can iterate them or can access them through indexing, it shows

> TypeError: 'DateTimeRange' object is not iterable

This approach does not work since i get the same results. Also even if i convert to str data type results are quite the same. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: _"This approach does not work since i get the same results"_. What results are those?

Comment: @Kevin Edited the question.